# Bricked Computer

Tags: data-recovery

So on my desktop, I decided to install Ubuntu 10.10, so I wiped it, the 10.04 system wasn't working anyway, but whenever I try to boot from a USB it tells me that there's a boot failure issue, and to hit enter, and when I put in a disk, the hardware doesn't load; keyboard, mouse, and the like, anything I can do? this hasn't happened before

Answer (score 9):

First thing to do is create another boot USB using the ISO you downloaded. If you used the "Create a Startup Disk" option from the Ubuntu menu, then try using `unetbootin` instead, it sometimes works when the Startup Disk Creator doesn't.

If it boots, select "Verify Disc" (Can't remember the exact name) to check that your ISO is valid. If this works, install again. If your boot-USB-stick does not pass the test, then download the ISO again, as it may have been corrupted. (You can check the ISO on-disk using the `md5sum` command and comparing it to md5 sums you find on the Ubuntu web page - google is your friend)

Comment: No worries, if you need more help, just comment here and I'll take a look at it.

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to MD5 test the ISO you put on the USB stick

Answer (score -4):

Did you completely 'wipe' your computer with DBAN < http://www.dban.org/ >? If not, download and burn this program to a disk. Then set your BIOS to open first with your DVD drive and restart your computer with this DBAN disk in place.

After several hours (depending on the size of your hard drive), your computer will be totally 'wiped' and you can then place your Ubuntu disk in your drive and restart your computer.

If everything is okay, Ubuntu should install normally.

Good luck!

Comment: Shouldn't be an issue, looks like the boot failure is with the USB driver not the hard disk.

Comment: It should be noted that this answer will permanently and irrevocably delete data.

Comment: It should also be noted that this is completely unnecessary if all you want to do is install Ubuntu.